# my windows xp laptop is coming up with a blue screen of death

Tags: windows-xp

I was going to do a system restore because my computer was not running well.

I was moving a big 2 GB file (it was an ISO file) but I switched the computer off because I thought it was done.

Later I switched it on because I was going to install windows 10 in virtual box but I got a blue screen of death and Unmountable_boot_volume.

I left it and then it booted normally to my desktop and I did a system restore.

When that was done it came up with no error and at the bottom it came up with 0x00000024 error over and over.

In my BIOS I have no option to boot from USB.

The laptop I have is an Acer travelmate 290

Comment: I've tried to clean up your question as the second paragraph was one **very long** sentence. Please review the edit and make sure it is OK.

Comment: Migrate the dump file to a working machine, use windbg to determine the cause of the crash, and provide us that info

Comment: If I have a bootable USB can I just move the files off the USB to a CD and let it boot off there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news I managed to fix it :-)

The way I did was

1. I got the Iso from pcriver.com
2. I made a bootable USB using Rufus for windows
3. I burned PLOP boot manager onto a disk as my bios does not support booting from a USB stick
4. Then I booted into PLOP boot manager
5. As every time I boot from USB, PLOP boot manager freezes and you will have to force boot USB 1.1 and use mode 2 if I were you!
6. And then if it says "press any key to boot from usb" I just pressed F1 and then any key
7. Then you will see "setup is inspecting system components" and then it should boot into windows setup
8. And when it installed it will go to a black screen for 5 minutes and it will say about the screen resulotion and it will auto adjust it to fix your screen
9. And you will see it does not have the desktop for a few minutes, that's because it is loading up a program for the .cab files
10. Enjoy windows xp!

The links to the files are:

http://pcriver.com/operating-systems/windows-xp-iso-download/

https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

Make sure you click plpbt-5.0.15.zip as I think it is the one that boots from USB

And when you extract it use the ISO file for the CD/DVD or the IMG file for floppy drives

Oh yeah one more thing,

If you are worried about it being unbootable it is bootable, I tested it and it worked :-)

And also does anyone have the link for the ralink wireless utility?

My computer only takes card bus for internet e.g Google.com?

Because when I was installing windows xp it took out my internet access so without the card bus software it is a pointless bit of plastic and metal with circuits in it!